# libqt5core5a no longer provides qtbase-abi

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, qt

I'm having some huge dependency issues here with trying to install MEGASync app, but I need to first install `libqt5core5a` but I cannot install it because it's telling me that `qtbase-abi-5.2.1` is no longer provided.

So where the hell do I even get `qtbase-abi` from now then? It's so stupid that you include one repository, but you remove certain packages that are dependant on it from being installed, that is required by its main core package in order to function. Why do Package maintainers do this? this is so broken, and stupid way to provide packages, then I'm left to source each individual DEB packages on my own from Launchpad or some other place, because the current repos doesn't even hold them anymore.

I have a separate version of Qt5 installed in `/opt/Qt` for version 5.9.3 from official source, but I can't even tell the system to use them because the whole PATH thing completely ignores it exists. Configuring Qt PATHS is never easy because they make it as complicated as possible so you can't do that with `qtchooser` command that it provides. Unless of course there's some other way of configuring this properly.

[image: MegaSync]
[image: libqt5core5a]

MEGASync (17.04 / 17.10)
libqt5core5a v5.7.1

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install this and it seemed to work fine. This is what I did:

1. Download MEGAsync from https://mega.nz/sync!linux. In my case I downloaded `megasync-xUbuntu_17.10_amd64.deb` by choosing "Ubuntu 17.10" from the drop down box.
2. Open terminal, go to the folder containing the downloaded file and execute `sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_17.10_amd64.deb`. This should also install any required dependencies.
3. Launch MEGAsync.

Comment: Insufficient. I have tried every version possible, and it's always telling me I'm missing some package, and that package can't be installed.

Comment: Could you update your question to show the output when you try to install it?

Comment: Updated with screenshots.

Comment: Could you also provide the version of Ubuntu you are using and the output from `dpkg -S libQt5Core` and `qmake --version`. Also, could you advise if you have tried to change your system to use the Qt version you installed in `/opt` and if so, what you tried.

Comment: version 17.04, and qmake version is 5.9.3, I changed the default config for Qt to point to the one in /opt for qmake and it's library directory.

Comment: I'd guess that you have not set that pointer to Qt installed in /opt correctly. Can you undo what you've done and then try installing MEGAsync?

Comment: @gsruk - I've already tried that before I did that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you update the question to show exactly how you changed the default config to point to the Qt in /opt?